# Bootstrap Div with text and image (aligned) in center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to align text and image in the center when it is in small devices. i tried to use text-align: center, but the text doesn't get aligned with the image. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:20px; ">
   <p style="height:125px; font-size: 14.4px; position: relative" class="text-responsive">
      <span style="position: absolute;top: 0;">
         <b>a long name goes here</b> <br> <br>
      </span>
      <span style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;">
      <span class="icon-clock"></span><small>8:00</small> <br>
      <span class="icon-location"></span><small>Singapore</small>
      </span>
   </p>
   <img style="max-height: 310px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310"/>
</div>

.text-responsive {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Here is what i am getting:
[image]

Here is what i would like to achieve:
[image]

I would really appreciate some help! Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Amaan's suggestion, I have replaced span with div, and it works!
Here's the code, if it helps anyone out there!

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bg" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
   <div style="font-size: 14.4px; max-width: 180px; height:125px; position:relative;" class="img-responsive">
      <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;">
         <b>a long name goes here</b>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align: left;position: absolute; bottom:0;">
         <div class="icon-clock"><small>8:00</small></div>
         <div class="icon-location"><small>Singapore</small></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <img style="max-height: 310px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a style of `text-align:center`in the outermost div as

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:20px;text-align:center">
 <p style="height:125px; font-size: 14.4px; position: relative" class="text-responsive">
  <span style="position: absolute;top: 0;">
     <b>a long name goes here</b> <br> <br>
  </span>
  <span style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;">
  <span class="icon-clock"></span><small>8:00</small> <br>
  <span class="icon-location"></span><small>Singapore</small>
  </span>
</p>
<img style="max-height: 310px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310"/>
</div>

.text-responsive {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: Like i mentioned, it doesn't work. it doesn't get aligned in the center. only the image gets aligned in the center, but not the text. the text gets aligned much more towards the left.

Comment: Once try removing each and every styling apart from text-align:center in the outermost div

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. if it did, i wouldn't be posting and asking for help.

Comment: Lastly just try replacing span with div, p or any header tag. Since span is an inline element it may create problem

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to replace span with div! It works after much troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

it may help you

```
<style>
.text-responsive {
text-align: center;
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}

```
</style>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:20px; ">
<div class =class="text-responsive">
<p style="height:125px; font-size: 14.4px; position: relative" class="text- responsive" >
  <span style=top: 0;">
     <b>a long name goes here</b> <br> <br>
  </span>
  <span style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;">
  <span class="icon-clock"></span><small>8:00</small> <br>
  <span class="icon-location"></span><small>Singapore</small>
  </span>
 </p>
<p class="text-responsive">
<img style="max-height: 310px;" class="img-responsive"   src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310"/>
```

Comment: i'm getting the same results as i was getting before. the text does not get aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your image this styles:

```
.img-responsive {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to put all the elements of the div in boostrap in center.
so you need to put:
`text-center` in class

```
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="padding-bottom:20px; ">
   <p style="height:125px; font-size: 14.4px; " >
      <span style="position: absolute;top: 0;">
         <b>a long name goes here</b> <br> <br>
      </span>
      <span style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;">
      <span class="icon-clock"></span><small>8:00</small> <br>
      <span class="icon-location"></span><small>Singapore</small>
      </span>
   </p>
   <img style="max-height: 310px;"  src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310"/>

</div>
```

And make a css file so you can styles there you code.. as you like.

Comment: Same as @Amaan's answer, the text doesn't get aligned.

Comment: @Amaan's need to open the developer mode in you browser and check the elements,

Comment: i did open developer mode. that's the most basic, isn't it?

Comment: img-responsive has nothing to do with it. the image is aligned to the center, the text is giving problem, not image.

Comment: you can see the in the responsive mode the text dev i center.

Comment: Sorry i do not see the you put the `class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 "`

Comment: All the div is `col-md-12` so to make it in center you need to put the `col-md-6` 
You can put all that in boostrap `class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 "`
you need to put only one. of those.

Comment: why do i even need col-md-6? i want the whole div to take over the whole screen when in smaller screen sizes, that's why i only need col-xs-12

Comment: Yes you put the whole div in `class="col-md-12 "`
and then your text in center. And you will work. i did now and it work.